# Is it true that $\mathbb{P}(\sum_n X_n \mathrm{\ converges}) = \mathbb{P}(\sum_n Y_n \mathrm{\ converges}) $ given condition.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X_n$ has the same distribution as $Y_n$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Is it true that $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n \mathrm{\ converges}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty Y_n \mathrm{\ converges}\right) $$

If necessary, you can assume that the sequence $(X_n)_n$ is independent and that the sequence $(Y_n)_n$ is independent.

**Attempt**:

Not really much. Putting $S_n:= \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$, we have

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n \mathrm{\ converges}\right)=\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n \to \infty} \leq\liminf_{n \to \infty} S_n )$$

but I don't know how to transform the info I got from one sequence to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If we assume that $(X_n)_n$ is independent and $(Y_n)_n$ is independent and $X_n$ has the same law as $Y_n$ for all $n$, then it is true. Indeed, the events $\{\sum_n X_n \mbox{ converges}\}$ and $\{\sum_n Y_n \mbox{ converges}\}$ can be expressed as countable unions and intersections of events of the form $\left\{\left\lvert \sum_{n=N}^MX_n\right\rvert \lt 1/k\right\}$ (respectively  $\left\{\left\lvert \sum_{n=N}^MY_n\right\rvert \lt 1/k\right\}$). In order words their probability can be expressed as the law of $(X_n)_n$ ($(Y_n)_n$ respectively) and the laws are the same.
- Without the independent assumption, it is not true: let $X$ be a random variable taking the values $-1$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$; $X_n=X/n$ for all $n$ and $Y_{2n}=X/2n$, $Y_{2n+1}=-X/(2n+1)$.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I'm filling in the steps. So, I see that we can write $\{\sum_n X_n \mathrm{\ converges}\} = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{p > q \geq n} \{|\sum_{j=q+1}^p X_j| \leq 1/k\}$. How can I proceed from here?

Comment: This set is $\{(X_n)\in B\}$ for some Borel set of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ endowed with the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: How exactly does this help? Are you using some form of infinite joint distribution or something like that (I only know that for a finite product we have $\mathbb{P}_{(X_1, \dots, X_n)}  = \mathbb{P}_{X_1} \otimes \dots \otimes \mathbb{P}_{X_n}$.

Comment: Ok, if you are not comfortable with infinite distributions, show that for all $N$ and all $k$, the events $  \bigcap_{p > q \geq N} \{|\sum_{j=q+1}^p X_j| \leq 1/k\}$ and $ \bigcap_{p > q \geq N} \{|\sum_{j=q+1}^p Y_j| \leq 1/k\}$ have the same probability.

Comment: I also don't know how I can show that? A little hint? Especially the intersection stands in the way.

Comment: Write $\bigcap_{p>q\geq N}$ as $\bigcap_{\ell>N}\bigcap_{N\leq q\lt p\leq \ell}A_{p,q}$ with $\{|\sum_{j=q+1}^p X_j| \leq 1/k\}=:A_{p,q}$. Let $B_\ell= \bigcap_{N\leq q\lt p\leq \ell}A_{p,q}$; the sequence $(B_\ell)$ decreases to $\bigcap_{\ell>N}\bigcap_{N\leq q\lt p\leq \ell}A_{p,q}$.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to proceed.